# Horizontal scrollbar of website is reset position when using Fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox, mousewheel

My website uses Fancybox to display item and mousewheel for horizontal mouse scroll.

Each time I scroll my page, then select an item, the horizontal scroll is set to position 0.
I want the scroll remains its position.

Please help me.

Comment: Works fine for me - http://jsfiddle.net/fCJuN/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fancybox is setting the .fancybox-lock class on the html...

```
.fancybox-lock {
    overflow: hidden !important; // <-- this is the problem
    width: auto;
}

.fancybox-lock {
    width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I edited your code and Its worked.

- beforeLoad:
- beforeClose:
- afterShow:

that is not necessary. I removed.

```
       var scrollPos = 0;
        $(".news_helper").fancybox({
            width: 512,
            fitToView: false,
            height: '100%',
            autoSize: false,
            closeClick: false,
            openEffect: 'none',
            closeEffect: 'none',
            mouseWheel: false,
        });
        $('html, body').mousewheel(function (event, delta, deltaX, deltaY) {
            this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 100);
            event.preventDefault();
        });
        $("img.lazy").lazyload({
            effect: "fadeIn",

        });
```

Check it [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/94qJ5/)